# Dealing with zeros when computing proportional change

Tags: data-transformation, proportion

I'm attempting to investigate the independence of the proportion of dividend payouts which is not linked to the movement of the stock index.

The data I have is in the form of a list of dividend payouts for given dates and also a time series of the price of the stock index.

My current attempt is as follows:

Since we are interested in movement, we have to look at some form of daily change. Since we are dealing with stocks, proportional change seems to most appropriate. Hence, we compute the proportional change of the stock index.

To see the proportional change of the dividend, I first convert it into a time series by forwards filling the data, and then calculate the proportional change. Obviously this is zero for many days.

We want to see the part of the movement which is independent from the movement of the index, and so we linearly regress the proportional change of each stock against the proportional change of the index and are left with some residuals.

Let's suppose we have two stocks, A and B. We want the residuals of A and B to be uncorrelated, since this would suggest that the residuals are just random noise, and not linked to some additional factor. Hence we compute the correlation between the residuals of A and B and hope this is small.

My problem is:
When computing the proportional change from day to day:
$$ \frac{x_i-x_{i-1}}{x_{i-1}} $$
We obviously have some issues dealing with the case $x_{i-1}=0$. If $x_i = 0$ then we have a $-100\%$ decrease, but the opposite obviously won't encode an infinite proportional increase.

What would be the best approach to get around this problem? Is considering proportional returns the right thing to do?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps proportional change is not a good metric.  Could you tell us why you want to compute this and how you intend to interpret it?

Comment: Hi whuber, I'm looking at a time series of two stock dividends, A and B. At current I'm taking proportional returns of the index containing A and B, proportional returns of the dividends for A and B, linearly regressing against the proportional returns of the dividend against the proportional returns of the index and then checking the correlation between the residuals of this linear regression.

Comment: Although that says *what* you are doing, it doesn't give us any information concerning *why* you are doing it, which makes it hard to help. It is usually the case that when you ask the problem you really have--which in this case sounds something like trying to understand the relationships between dividend streams and indexes--then you will get helpful answers, but when you try to ask some kind of abstract version of your question, you typically get answers to the abstraction that are either useless or wrong for your actual situation.

Comment: Apologies, I thought this might be a fairly standard problem with a list of solutions appriopriate to various tasks. The aim of my calculation is to determine to what extent the dividend streams are purely a consequence of movement in the index, and to what extent are there other factors.

The regression against the index returns removes the movement of the index, and we are left with the residuals of A and B. If A and B are highly correlated, then it would be more likely that we are missing a factor affecting the dividend streams.

 I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Ordinarily one would not go about analyzing such data in the way you have proposed. That is why I am trying to encourage you to rewrite your question so that it solicits advice about more effective statistical procedures, rather than asking how to work around an inherent problem with a procedure that appears to be inappropriate.